# LLVM Numbering isn't starting at %0

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

Why is the first code block valid, while the second one isn't? When I'm looking at the docs, I see `%0` used plenty of times, but when I try to use it (in order), I get an error from `llc`:

```
llc: error: llc: test.ll:2:2: error: instruction expected to be numbered '%1'
        %0 = add i64 %x, %y
        ^
```

```
define i64 @add(i64 %x, i64 %y) {
    %1 = add i64 %x, %y
    ret i64 %1
}

define i64 @main() {
    ret i64 0
}
```

```
define i64 @add(i64 %x, i64 %y) {
    %0 = add i64 %x, %y
    ret i64 %0
}

define i64 @main() {
    ret i64 0
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first unnamed entity is basic block. This is why the first instruction should use `%1` in unnamed basic block.

```
define i64 @add(i64 %x, i64 %y) {
entry:
    %0 = add i64 %x, %y
    ret i64 %0
}
```

should work